# Encryption NSString AES256EncryptWithKey and AES256DecryptWithKey for ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

Any framework or third party support `AES256EncryptWithKey` and `AES256DecryptWithKey` for `NSString`.

How to do `AES256EncryptWithKey` and `AES256DecryptWithKey` of `NSString` in ios 4.2 and 4.3

@ALL help me out

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SSCrypto](http://septicus.com/products/opensource/) for this purpose.
Its a wrapper around OpenSSL framework. Its pretty straight forward.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

As of now, in 2021, I used this: https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor

Comment: AES encryption has been on iOS for years. In 2021 you should be using CryptoKit (since iOS 13).